# Get duplicates except first occurrence in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to return duplicates except first occurance in an array of objects based of the place and keyword. Both should match and return the documents in an new array. Here is my trial run:

```
var things = [
                {place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 0},
                {place: 'hi', id: 1},
                {place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 2},
                {place: 'hello', keyword: 'man', id: 3}
            ]
var duplicates = [];

things.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(things.indexOf(item.place) != index && things.indexOf(item.keyword) != index) {
        duplicates.push(item);
    }
});
```

Expected output:

```
[{place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 2}]
```

Any help would be great (without any frameworks, just ES6 or older). Thanks

EDIT: It should match multiple specified values such as keyword and place.

Comment: I would consider using *array.find* in a loop as it returns the first matching element.

Comment: Based on your description I would expect `{place: 'hello', keyword: 'man', id: 3}` to be in the output as well

Comment: @adelin it should only match keyword and place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the same keys and filter if the count is greater than one with an object for counting

```js
const
    getKey = o => keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|'),
    keys = ['place', 'keyword'],
    things = [{ place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 0 }, { place: 'hi', id: 1 }, { place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 2 }, { place: 'hello', keyword: 'man', id: 3 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    duplicates = things.filter(o =>
        (k => (hash[k] = (hash[k] || 0) + 1) > 1)
        (getKey(o))
    );
  
console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: The second approach is perfect tbh. Even if OP means index > 1, it's just matter of changing the operator.

Comment: I forget to mention in the original question, it should check for place and keyword both.

Comment: @ninaScholz its not working as expected as its only returning one occurrence of the duplicated item. See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2ed1pxt/1/

Comment: ok, i got it. chencge the counting condition to `> 1` in `(k => (hash[k] = (hash[k] || 0) + 1) > 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could group the items based on `place` and then get the first item from those groups with `length > 1`

```js
const things = [{ place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 0 }, { place: 'hi', id: 1 }, { place: 'hello', keyword: 'hey', id: 2 }, { place: 'hello', keyword: 'man', id: 3 }];

const merged = things.reduce((r, a) => {
  (r[a.place] = r[a.place] || []).push(a)
  return r
}, {})

const final = Object.values(merged)
                    .filter(a => a.length > 1)
                    .map(a => a[1])

console.log(final)
```

Comment: result should be `id: 2`.

Comment: @NinaScholz ah, reread the question now. OP wants *all* the duplicates except the first one or just the duplicate at index 1?

Comment: interesting question. but if all except the first duplicate, then the above expected output has to be different. maybe it's just bad wording or the wrong result (which usually is correct).

Comment: @NinaScholz you're right. It's the duplicate at index 1 since there is no `id: 3` in the expected output.

Comment: I forget to mention in the original question, it should check for place and keyword both.

Comment: @ninaScholz this is the result to expect: https://jsfiddle.net/yo50wxcu/2/

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is that you'll have to track the objects you have seen in order to do it how you want.

```
const seen = [];
const duplicates = [];

things.forEach(item => {
  const sawItem = seen.find(seenItem => item.place === seenItem.place && item.keyword === seenItem.keyword)
  if (sawItem) {
     duplicates.push(sawItem);
  } else {
    seen.push(sawItem);
  }
});
```

This isn't a very efficient algorithm however, so I'm curious to see a better way to do it.

Comment: This did not work for me, getting error: cannot find place of undefined seen as seen is not defined.

Comment: It is defined with `const seen = [];`?